# Issue sending digitally signed emails to Gmail from php

Tags: php, mime-types, digital-signature, phpbb, smime

I am trying to send digitally signed email messages via PHPBB. I have it working well for all our exchange emails and all the various clients, but it is not working for gmail users. It seems almost like google is not processing/reading the multipart mime type. Maybe I am missing something silly or easy? Thank you for looking!

Here is an example of a test email, the cert is blocked out with #:

> This is an S/MIME signed message
>
> ------############################  Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> Hello admin,
>
> Congratulations. If you received this email, phpBB is correctly
>   configured  to send emails.
>
> In case you require assistance, please visit the phpBB support forums
>   -  https://www.phpbb.com/community/
>
> --
>
> ------############################  Content-Type:
>   application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s" 
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="smime.p7s"
>
> #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>   
>   #
>
> ------############################--

Here is snippet of the code I am using:

```
// Send message ...
$mail_to = ($to == '') ? 'undisclosed-recipients:;' : $to;
$fp = fopen("/var/www/ssl/ext/phpbbservices/digests/includes/msg.txt", "w"); 
$this->msg = "".'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\n" .  $this->msg . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $this->msg); 
fclose($fp);

openssl_pkcs7_sign("/var/www/ssl/ext/phpbbservices/digests/includes/msg.txt", "/var/www/ssl/ext/phpbbservices/digests/includes/signed.txt", file_get_contents("/var/www/ssl/ext/phpbbservices/digests/includes/publicCert.pem"), array(file_get_contents("/var/www/ssl/ext/phpbbservices/digests/includes/privateKey.pem"), 'PASSWORD_FOR_PRIVATE_KEY'), $headers); 
$data = file_get_contents("/var/www/ssl/ext/phpbbservices/digests/includes/signed.txt");


$parts = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
$newHeader = explode("\n", $parts[0]);

$newMessage =  $parts[1];


$result = phpbb_mail($mail_to, $this->subject, $newMessage, $newHeader, PHP_EOL, $err_msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it was a simple thing!
The exchange headers did not match what I had in the signed.txt processed file. So I dug into it, and found that the phpBB system was creating a header, including Content-Type: text/html; charset=charset="iso-8859-1”. So the header had two, that one, and the correct "Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256”;” Exchange modifies the headers and just ignored/cleaned the first entry, while google ignored the second Content type and just used the first.

So ultimately I just had to comment off the phpBB header entry in that part of the code that set the Content-Type.